# getAllVisibleItems() not working in magento 2

Tags: magento2.3.1

> $order = $this->_orderFactory->create()->load($orderId);

i have order id, now i want to access all the visible ordered items from db using 
`getAllVisibleItems()`**.anyone help me**

Comment: Can you pls add your orderFactory's class?

Comment: \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory, already added

Comment: $this->_orderFactory = $orderFactory; then include this one

Comment: Try this: `$order = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
$orderItems = $order->getAllVisibleItems();`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this..

```
$orderId = 1;
$orderItemsRow = [];
$allVisibleItems = $this->_orderFactory->create()->load($orderId)->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach ($allVisibleItems as $orderItem) {
    if ($orderItem->getProductType() == 'simple') {
        $orderItemsRow[] = [
            'sku' => $orderItem->getSku(), //Product Code
            'qty' => (int)$orderItem->getQtyToShip(), //QTY Ordered
            'name' => $orderItem->getName(), //QTY Ordered
        ];
    } else if ($orderItem->getProductType() == 'configurable' || $orderItem->getProductType() == 'bundle') {
        foreach ($orderItem->getChildrenItems() as $childItem) {
            $orderItemsRow[] = [
                'sku' => $childItem->getSku(), //Product Code
                'qty' => (int)$childItem->getQtyOrdered(), //QTY Ordered
                'name' => $childItem->getName(), //QTY Ordered
            ];
        }
    }
}
print_r($orderItemsRow);
```

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why **getAllVisibleItems()** not working. It should be working.

Still, try to use this below code:

```
$_items = $order->getItemsCollection();

 foreach ($_items as $item) {
    if ($item->getParentItem()) continue;
    echo $item->getSku();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`getAllVisibleItems()` is definitely doing what it was meant for. One has to find out a way to make it work per one's requirements. I have had to do something like below to capture only the row of simple product for the processing in my back-end app.

if ($item->getProductType() == "configurable") {
    continue;
}
// Only simple product details follow
```